# how to select one of each kind from database in php

Tags: php, mysql

let's say i have a database containing data like this

```
id  userfrom userto body
1   a         b      hello
2   b         a      i am b
3   a         b      everyone
4   b         a      this is great
```

now i want to select 1 of each a and b or you can say i want to show only 1 post of both a and b so what should be the mysql query for this in php and my query goes like this tell me what changes should i have to accept to get the data
sorry for writing this much long code

```
<?php
                                $connection10=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','123456789','register');
        $selectquery="select * from messages where userfrom='$msg' or userto='$msg'";
        $resultquery=mysqli_query($connection10,$selectquery);
while($rowstand=mysqli_fetch_array($resultquery))
        {
            $userfrom1=$rowstand['userfrom'];
            $userto1=$rowstand['userto'];
            $body=$rowstand['msgbody'];
                $date=$rowstand['date'];
        $searchquery="select * from register where id='$userto1'";
            $searchresult=mysqli_query($connection10,$searchquery);
            while($bigrow=mysqli_fetch_array($searchresult))
            {
                $profileimage=$bigrow['profilepic'];
            $myfirstname=$bigrow['firstname'];
            $mylastname=$bigrow['lastname'];
            }
        echo '<a href="viewmessages.php?id='.$userto1.'"><img src="'.$profileimage.'" height="50" width="50"></a>'.$myfirstname.' '.$mylastname.'<br>'.$body.'<hr>';}
?>
```

Comment: thanks man that solved my problem

Comment: Assigning a string to an unexpected constant `query` won't get you anywhere. That string might actually be a valid query, but PHP won't magically execute, fetch and process the results for you. Please learn the basics. There's only 1 line of PHP in your question, and even that's wrong. ATM, it looks as if you're waiting for somebody to post copy-pastable code that does what you need

Comment: dude you want code than here goes my whole code

Comment: Now please explain how that code relates to your question? Where in your code is the problem?

Comment: dude i just want to give an example but apparently as it turns out nobody here likes simple language

Comment: On the contrary, people here like simple, concise, to-the-point questions with code snippets relating to the question, example input and output and a clear problem statement. Maybe read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: that's what i tried at first but as it turn out some user has problem with that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `GROUP BY` command, like this :
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a0057/5/0

Answer (score 0):

`select DISTINCT name,id,post from users`

or

`select DISTINCT name,id,post from users GROUP BY name`

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with `GROUP BY`, which will return 2 results in your example. It might be nice to concatenate the posts belonging to the same *name* using `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
SELECT name, GROUP_CONCAT(post SEPARATOR ' ') 
FROM users
GROUP BY name;
```

Output:

> a |   hello everyone
>
> b |   i am b this is great

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5cf15/1).